# Customizing URLs with prefix in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I have this html:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="index.php/Page1">Page 01</a></   
   <li><a href="index.php/Page2">Page 02</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php/Page3">Page 03</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I *need* to use the `index.php/`prefix in all links due to the   server of my university
(I can't change it). The way is done above, it works fine to go straightfoward from home to any page, but if I try to access a page from another page, I get a wrong URL and Can't access the page:

Examples:

**Home**
`http://localhost/php-project/public/`

**Page1** (From home)
FROM: `http://localhost/php-project/public/`
TO:   `http://localhost/php-project/public/index.php/Page1`

**Page2** (From home)
FROM: `http://localhost/php-project/public/`
TO: `http://localhost/php-project/public/index.php/Page2`

**Page1** (From Page2)
FROM: `http://localhost/php-project/public/index.php/Page2`
TO: `http://localhost/php-project/public/index.php/index.php/Page1`

as you can see, the prefix repeats itself. I have no idea how to do it to work right.

Any ideas?

Comment: The links are relative, you most likely need to use `<a href="/index.php/Page1"`, Note the / before index.php

Comment: @Karl Already tried. If I do that I get `http://localhost/index.php/import` and cant access the page, missing the ´public/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem:

- I created a helper function on laravel's `helper.php`

`function custom_url($routename)
{
   return str_replace("index.php", "",URL($routename));
}`

And used like this:

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="{{custom_url('index.php/Page1')}}">Importar Histórico</a></li>
     <li><a href="{{custom_url('index.php/Page2')}}">Alocar Disciplina</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it using the method `forceRootUrl` on the class `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator`.

Example:

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider
public function boot()
{
    // Instance of Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator
    $urlGenerator = $this->app['url'];

    // Instance of Illuminate\Http\Request
    $request = $this->app['request'];

    // Grabbing the root url
    $root = $request->root();

    // Add the suffix
    $rootSuffix = '/index.php';
    if (!ends_with($root, $rootSuffix)) {
        $root .= $rootSuffix;
    }

    // Finally set the root url on the UrlGenerator
    $urlGenerator->forceRootUrl($root);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Route prefix.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'/index.php/'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', ['as'=>home, 'uses'=>'HomeController@index']);
    //Include all your routes here. And in your view, link any page with the route name. 
    // eg: <a href="{{URL::route('home')}}"></a>
});
```

Comment: It does not replace the prefix, it just keep adding the prefix for each click ;s