# Laravel - Root Url suffix and route prefix inconsistency

Tags: laravel, routes

We have a test site with laravel 4, which is on a **subfolder** on the server. So it is on `thedomain/sitename`. This have caused big challenges with routing.  The routes became wrong, like: `thedomain/about` instead of `thedomain/oursite/about`.

I added a Url root suffix`'oursite'` by using the Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator (following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234328/customizing-urls-with-prefix-in-laravel#answer-35238755)).

All urls in the templates became correct, but they don't match anything in `routes.php` which still treats it without the suffix.

I tried adding a [route prefix](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-prefixing) . Now the urls typed into the address bar worked. But all the urls in the templates became wrong, for instance **`thedomain/oursite/oursite/about`**.

So this seems inconsistent - why is the root Url suffix added to all the routes when they are echoed in the templates (like  `<a href="{{ route('about'); }}` ) but they are interpreted **without** the suffix in routes.php!?

How can I get around that? I thought I was close to solving this. Or could I use route filter to redirect on every link?

Comment: Have you tried routing without rewriting index.php so your route would be `thedomain/oursite/index.php/about`

Comment: No I haven't tried it. How is that enabled in Laravel?

Comment: its part of your .htaccess or web.config if on IIS, it has nothing to do with laravel and everything to do with your web server configuration. Essentially you want index.php to show up before your route.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution: maybe use subdomain like `sitename.thedomain.com` instead of subfolder. If your server provider not support subdomains, change provider :P